# option:selected in jquery is counting in the hidden option as well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a requirement in the project where I am supposed to move on an option from the first dropdown to the second dropdown on click of an add button and vice versa on click of remove button.

Here is the HTML:

```js
jQuery( "#term_add" ).click(function() {
  addTerm();
});

jQuery( "#term_rem" ).click(function() {
  remTerm();
});
// this function is called when user clicks the add button in the terms section
function addTerm() {

  if ( jQuery("#all_terms :selected").length === 0 ) {
    alert('Please select at least one term from the Terms drop-down to add');
    return;
}

jQuery("#all_terms option:selected").each( function()
{ 

  var new_elem = jQuery(this).val();

  // show the option which was hidden by default
  jQuery('#terms option[value="' + new_elem + '"]').show();

  jQuery(this).hide();

});

  // Unselect the options selected in the all_terms dropdown
  jQuery("#all_terms option:selected").removeAttr("selected");

  // trigger cascading
  // Do Something
}

// this function is called when user clicks the remove button in the terms section
function remTerm() {

  var count_all_the_visible_options_in_terms_dropdown = 0;
  jQuery("#terms option").each(function()
  {
    if(!jQuery(this).is(':hidden')){
      count_all_the_visible_options_in_terms_dropdown = count_all_the_visible_options_in_terms_dropdown + 1;
    }
  });

  // If the user has not removed all the options from the "Selected Terms" drop-down then cascading should restart.
  console.log( 'count_all_the_visible_options_in_terms_dropdown 1 => ' + count_all_the_visible_options_in_terms_dropdown);
  if ( count_all_the_visible_options_in_terms_dropdown === 0 ) {
    // Do something

    } else {
    // Do something
    }

  if ( !count_all_the_visible_options_in_terms_dropdown ) {
    alert('Please select at least one term from the Selected Terms drop-down to remove');
    return;
  }

  jQuery("#terms option").each(function()
  {

    // Add $(this) to your selected list
    if(jQuery(this).is(':selected')){ 

      var new_elem = jQuery(this).val();

      // display the removed option in available terms dropdown..
      jQuery('#all_terms option[value="' + new_elem + '"]').show();

      // hide the option in the selected terms dropdown
      jQuery(this).hide();

  }

});

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="formTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td><h5>Available Terms</h5></td>
    <td>
        <div id="terms_div">
            <select multiple="" id="all_terms" name="all_terms" style="width:100px;">
       <option value="Fall 2014" title="Fall 2014" style="display: block;">Fall 2014</option>
                <option value="Fall 2015" title="Fall 2015" style="display: block;">Fall 2015</option>
                <option value="Fall 2018" title="Fall 2018" style="display: block;">Fall 2018</option>
                <option value="SPRING 2015" title="SPRING 2015" style="display: block;">SPRING 2015</option>
                <option value="SPRING 2016" title="SPRING 2016" style="display: block;">SPRING 2016</option>
                <option value="SUMMER 2016" title="SUMMER 2016" style="display: block;">SUMMER 2016</option>
                <option value="Spring 2017" title="Spring 2017" style="display: block;">Spring 2017</option>                                  
   </select>
  </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="title" style="vertical-align:middle;padding:20px;">
        <input class="btn_cn" title="Add terms to the report" type="button" id="term_add" name="term_add" value="add >>">
        <br><br>
        <input class="btn_cn" title="Remove terms from the report" type="button" id="term_rem" name="term_rem" value="<< remove">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
 <td class="title width20" style="width:0em;"><h5>Selected Terms</h5></td>
    <td>
        <div id="selected_terms_div">
            <select multiple="" class="filter menuItems" id="terms" name="terms" style="width:100px;">
       <option value="Fall 2014" title="Fall 2014" style="display: none;">Fall 2014</option>
                <option value="Fall 2015" title="Fall 2015" style="display: none;">Fall 2015</option>
                <option value="Fall 2018" title="Fall 2018" style="display: none;">Fall 2018</option>
                <option value="SPRING 2015" title="SPRING 2015" style="display: none;">SPRING 2015</option>
                <option value="SPRING 2016" title="SPRING 2016" style="display: none;">SPRING 2016</option>
                <option value="SUMMER 2016" title="SUMMER 2016" style="display: none;">SUMMER 2016</option>
                <option value="Spring 2017" title="Spring 2017" style="display: none;">Spring 2017</option>                                  
   </select>
  </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

As the first step, click remove button

```
count_all_the_visible_options_in_terms_dropdown 1 => 0  -- correct
```

Now add all the FALL terms ( terms starting with FALL).

click delete button once again ( Nothing is selected in second dropdown )

```
count_all_the_visible_options_in_terms_dropdown 1 => 3 -- correct
```

Now select at least two terms and click remove.

```
count_all_the_visible_options_in_terms_dropdown 1 => 3 -- **INCORRECT**
```

I am not understanding why is this happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amending the visibility of `option` elements is notoriously unreliable. You can make the logic more accurate by actually moving the elements between `select` instead of hiding or showing their counterparts. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#term_add").click(function() {
    addTerm();
    sortTerms();
  });

  $("#term_rem").click(function() {
    remTerm();
    sortTerms();
  });

  function addTerm() {
    if ($("#all_terms :selected").length === 0) {
      alert('Please select at least one term from the Terms drop-down to add');
      return;
    }

    $("#all_terms option:selected").appendTo('#terms').prop('selected', false);
  }

  function remTerm() {
    if ($("#terms :selected").length === 0) {
      alert('Please select at least one term from the Selected Terms drop-down to remove');
      return;
    }

    $("#terms option:selected").appendTo('#all_terms').prop('selected', false);
  }

  function sortTerms() {
    $('#terms, #all_terms').each(function() {
      $(this).children('option').sort(function(a, b) {
        return $(a).data('sort') < $(b).data('sort') ? -1 : 1;
      }).appendTo(this);
    });
  }
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 100px;
}

.title {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="formTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h5>Available Terms</h5>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="terms_div">
        <select multiple="" id="all_terms" name="all_terms">
          <option value="Fall 2014" data-sort="1" title="Fall 2014">Fall 2014</option>
          <option value="Fall 2015" data-sort="2" title="Fall 2015">Fall 2015</option>
          <option value="Fall 2018" data-sort="3" title="Fall 2018">Fall 2018</option>
          <option value="SPRING 2015" data-sort="4" title="SPRING 2015">SPRING 2015</option>
          <option value="SPRING 2016" data-sort="5" title="SPRING 2016">SPRING 2016</option>
          <option value="SUMMER 2016" data-sort="6" title="SUMMER 2016">SUMMER 2016</option>
          <option value="Spring 2017" data-sort="7" title="Spring 2017">Spring 2017</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="title">
      <input class="btn_cn" title="Add terms to the report" type="button" id="term_add" name="term_add" value="add &gt;&gt;">
      <br><br>
      <input class="btn_cn" title="Remove terms from the report" type="button" id="term_rem" name="term_rem" value="&lt;&lt; remove">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="title width20">
      <h5>Selected Terms</h5>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="selected_terms_div">
        <select multiple="" class="filter menuItems" id="terms" name="terms"></select>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Also note that jQuery 1.8.0 is very outdated. You should upgrade to 3.x

Comment: we thought about it but the client wants the list to be ordered as it was initially. so implementing that is a much tedious task so thought of this solution.

Comment: Not really. All you need is a `sort()` call.

Comment: I updated the code in the question to show you how to do this

Comment: I had to change the sort function to this work.

        function sortTerms() {
            $('#terms, #all_terms').each(function() { 
                $(this).children('option').sort(function(a, b) {
                    return $(a).val() < $(b).val() ? -1 : 1;
                }).appendTo(this);
            });
        }

Comment: I added the `data-sort` as the original order is not alphabetical, but glad you got it working regardless.